# Updating app on device with .xib removed crashes app

Tags: ios, crash, uitableview, xib

I have an older version of an app installed on a device.  In my new version I no longer had use of a .xib file as it changed from something complex to just a table view and I can instantiate it in code.

However, when I build and run on the device it crashes as it still tries to load the controller from the .xib file contained in the older app, and complains about a key/value pair missing for a UILabel.

For example:

SomeViewController.h (UITableViewController)
SomeViewController.m
SomeViewController.xib (removed in new version)

```
SomeViewController *controller = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];

    if (self)
    {
    }

    return self;
}
```

Even though I call "initWithStyle" it still tries to load the pre-existing .xib!

My current solution is to create SomeViewController.xib with a blank UITableView.

I suspect however, that when users update the app from the app store it will overwrite the entire app and not leave anything behind.

Is this true?  Do app updates overwrite the existing app or does it leave lingering .xib files?

Now I have to test the older version with every other view to insure there is no other problems lingering.

Reading through the developer text on NIB's:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html

Perhaps I found a bug?

Another option is for me to re-name the class to something else like SomeController so as to avoid automatically loading the associated .xib file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has addressed this issue in the following technical note regarding testing iOS app updates:

[Technical Note TN2285](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2285/_index.html)

Comment: Summary: Building and running an app with Xcode only sends changed files and can create a "frankenbuild". Use Adhoc builds for testing.

Comment: Thanks! I read some posts recently on the necessity of testing adhoc builds prior to publishing to insure that a variety of issues are handled. Adding to my test checklist.

Comment: Glad I could help. I just ran into this piece of documentation while searching for a way to test a build so that I could avoid the exact same issue you were having.

Comment: We are seeing this happen on TestFlight builds, is this a known issue with TestFlight? I assumed they would be complete reinstalls.

Answer (score 1):

Two recommandations:

- Have you tried rebooting Xcode and the device that you use for your tests? (I have a long record of Xcode messing up cache management and keep using older versions of files)
- Are you sure that your XIB file is not referenced by another one? (perhaps your main view has a Tab Bar Controller where you left the name of the XIB you removed)

Comment: The problem is that the .xib already exists on the device within the app (in the manifest). Cleaned, rebuilt, reboot, the NEW update does not help. The problem is not that the .xib exists in the existing app. It's that the initWithStyle methods is still trying to automatically load @"SomeViewController.xib" (auto association - iOS 5 or 6 thing?)

Comment: Also, I did a 'grep' on the entire project and the SomeViewController.xib is non-existent. It's in the old app on the device however. I should note I am re-creating the old app from SVN.  I deleted the app from the device, rebuilt the old app, and re-installed to verify the issue.

Comment: Did you grep "SomeViewController.xib" or just "SomeViewController" ?

Comment: Both. I think there is a bug with the framework. It tries to load the .xib in the pre-existing app but sees that the outlets are not connected. Anyway, for now I simply added a .xib so that it will overwrite the existing one. In the next version I will remove it.

Comment: I ran into the same problem with another .xib. However, this time I restarted Xcode as well as the simulator and it appears to work okay. I thought I had did that last time (working too many hours). I built and installed an older version on the simulator, restarted Xcode plus the simulator, built and installed the new version on the simulator, and the error does not occur.  I can only hope that when binaries are distributed on the App Store that the entire binary is overwritten with no side-affects from older .xib files.