# How to update an app via adhoc build?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ad-hoc-distribution

Usually when I want to see how our app behaves when upgraded. I download a fresh installation from Appstore and connect the device via cable to the mac, to deploy the latest version on the same device.

This way I retain the data and see how it acts up upon upgrade.

In our latest app version we have removed a `~ipad.xib` file, repeating this approach is not enough as Xcode only updates files and doesn't remove former files.  Hence the app crashes when it tries to load a non existing xib file.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<FTAccountViewController 0x15d3eb50> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key reminderDate.'
```

Someone on SO has asked the same [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136848/updating-app-on-device-with-xib-removed-crashes-app). The solution is apparently to use an adhoc build.

The way I understand it, I have to archive the app via Xcode and distribute it as enterprise app and open the ipa file. iTunes will ask me if it should replace the existing app in the library, which is fine.

However how do I sync back the replaced ipa to my iPad?  Sync doesn't do it, as it thinks the app is already installed. Removing it is no option as the data will be lost.  Hence I can't really emulate an app upgrade.

Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect your iPad with the cable, it will be visible in Xcode, under Organizer > Devices, on the left side. Provided your IPA is provisioned for your iPad's UDID, you can just drag-n-drop the IPA from Finder onto the Device. It will even show installation errors under Console.

Re-read your question. Are you saying you want to try the new IPA, and then restore the previous (older) IPA with the data intact? I've tried installing an older IPA over the newer one with the above method, and it worked.

However I recommend to get **[iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/ifunboxmac/)**. Among other things, it allows to store/backup a currently installed app and restore it later. Verify what it does though.